# Cannot authorize the Slack CLI with my Slack workspace

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I was following [this tutorial](https://api.slack.com/future/quickstart#authorize-cli) to authorize the Slack CLI with my workspace but the slash command `/slackauthticket` is not recognized.

I am getting this error:

```
/slackauthticket is not a valid command. In Slack, all messages that start with the "/" character are interpreted as commands.
If you are trying to send a message and not run a command, try preceding the "/" with an empty space.
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

I am using Slack v4.27.154 and Slack CLI v1.9.0.

How can I get this to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that this feature is in closed beta, which is why I can't use it.